# call spring action from jquery without ajax for multiple buttons like view edit etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on Spring MVC. I have a page having list of items in table. I need jquery to pick up the radio selected and then user can click on view or edit or delete. According to the button clicked, ajax block invokes proper action with the form object serialized and the id goes to the action for processing.
Everything went fine till here.

Then, when the action returns back to ajax success: block

```
    $.ajax({
    type : "post",
    data : str,
    url : newUrl ,
    async : false,
    success : function(data) {    <----- here
```

I need to redirect to page action has in its view object. Instead, as we know, its ajax, so I need to show the result in some div on that page itself. But I need to go to the page directed by spring action. Please help me do this. 
In short, I don't want to show the details on a pop up but another page. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get url of page directed by page action and use following statement to redirect page

```
window.location = pathReturned;
```

above statement will simply redirect users' browser window. So if you may require to persist state of the page.

Comment: but i have form object containing values like details of the selected record that i need to show on next page. i can't simply redirect to some url. it has to be view of modelAndView object like it happens normally in spring.

Comment: You are then left with two choices, either submit the form rather than ajax or Persist Model, return view url, redirect to view and generate view using persisted model, so you need not to repopulate model (and also not process request). A working kind of example would be login of linkedin, they login using ajax, if not authenticated they show a message, but if authenticated then they redirect you to some logged in view.

Comment: can u give code example of this? I have banged my head a lot on this but can't figure out exactly.